# How to add Progress bar for mpdf

Tags: php, mpdf

I have generated pdf through mpdf library , my pdf take 4-5 minutes to generate pdf.
i want add percentage progress bar to show progress at the time of generate pdf.

how can i add javascript or php code for percentage progress bar to show progress

Comment: Check here https://mpdf.github.io/reference/mpdf-functions/startprogressbaroutput.html

Comment: thanks for your reply
I have checked mpdf functions but i got some error

Comment: What error you are facing?

Comment: have checked your given link but getting some error i made changes according to given suggestion. in config.php i made $this->progressBar = 1; and added code $mpdf->StartProgressBarOutput(); $mpdf->Output(); exit; but it redirect at time of pdf generate like

http://localhost/opt/lampp/htdocs/myfoldername/wp-content/plugins/products-pdf/pdf_data/mpdf60/includes/out.php

not found
 is there any other way to generate progress bar. ot solution for that

Comment: how to add progress bar for before generate pdf file
how can i get total page and how to add code based on total pdf page
if there any custom code please help me

Answer (score 0):

```
define('_MPDF_URI','../');     // must be  a relative or absolute URI - not a file system path

$mpdf = new mPDF();

$mpdf->StartProgressBarOutput(2);

$mpdf->WriteHTML('You will hardly have time to see the progress bars!');

$mpdf->Output();
```

From source [Link](https://mpdf.github.io/reference/mpdf-functions/startprogressbaroutput.html#example-1)

Comment: thanks for your reply.
I have checked your given link but getting some  error
i made changes according to given suggestion. 
in config.php i made $this->progressBar = 1;
and added code 
$mpdf->StartProgressBarOutput();
$mpdf->Output(); exit;
but it redirect at time of pdf generate  like 
http://localhost/opt/lampp/htdocs/myfoldername/wp-content/plugins/products-pdf/pdf_data/mpdf60/includes/out.php

id there ant other way to generate progress bar

Comment: Did you pass your absolute url?

Comment: yes i have passed absolute path for include mpdf file

require_once PDF_CATALOG__PLUGIN_DIR . 'pdf_data/mpdf60/mpdf.php';

Answer (score 0):

Try to use this method:

https://mpdf.github.io/reference/mpdf-functions/startprogressbaroutput.html

At the bottom of page is example.

Comment: thanks for your reply.
I have checked your given link but getting some  error
i made changes according to given suggestion. 
in config.php i made $this->progressBar = 1;
and added code 
$mpdf->StartProgressBarOutput();
$mpdf->Output(); exit;
but it redirect at time of pdf generate  like 
http://localhost/opt/lampp/htdocs/myfoldername/wp-content/plugins/products-pdf/pdf_data/mpdf60/includes/out.php

Comment: how to add javascript  progress bar for pdf, i 'm not able to add javascript code to show progress